# Linux restrict user to specific folder in var/www

Tags: command-line, permissions, ssh, apache2

My apache root `/var/www/html/` contains the following folders.

1. myapp
2. test
3. testapp

I want to create a new user to access only `testapp` folder (read/write). Other folders shouldn't be read.

I created a new user for for the group `www-data` (as www-data is the owner of the /var/www/html/) and I'm able to login via ssh as well. Now the problem is the new user is having access to all the 3 folders above. I need to restrict the user to have access only to testapp folder. (Other folders shouldn't be read by the new user)

Some people suggested to use `chroot` but it is unclear for me. Is there any way to restrict the www-data user only to a specific folder?

Comment: Just to mention it: The websites should be child's of www not of html, html is just the default website!

Comment: @Info-Screen that's fine. But that's not the issue here

Comment: Can't you just change the group of `testapp` and then add new user to that group.

Comment: Can you run the following in the terminal and add the output to the question - `ls -l /var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your new user testapp:

You have to remove read access for "other" of all files and folders. Issue the following commands:

1. `chmod -R o-r /`
2. `chown -R :testapp /var/www/html/testapp`
3. `chmod -R g+rwx /var/www/html/testapp`

Remove your new user from the `www-data` group, but remember when `www-data` cannot read files, it won't be readable on your website